# How to get planned events of a user using Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to display on a website the planned events of my facebook user account.

I use this link, with the access token of my app.
https://graph.facebook.com/{$fb_user_id}/events/attending/?access_token={$access_token_app};

I tried several times with different accounts, but I always get an empty data array, or only events that were created by the account itself.
Maybe it's because the access to planned events of a user is restricted ? 
Do I need a particular access_token ? Or an authentification ?

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the 'user_events' permission granted to be able to view a user's events. Have you checked that?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The issue is that I would prefer to avoid any kind of visible authentification because the app will be displayed in public. How can I get an user_events permission without a facebook pop-up showing ? (I am the owner of the user account from which I would like to get the events)

Comment: That's simple: You can't, and this is by design

Comment: Finally I managed to do things differently. Thanks for your help ! Have a nice day.